# Pictures overlapping when adding to word doc

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I have a word document where I am adding two pictures to it via C# code. When I am opening the word file after program finishes, I could see that the two pics are getting overlapped. Is there a way to have the pics one after the other ?

Here is the code which I am using :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();         
WordApp.Documents.Add();         
WordApp.Visible = true;         
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
doc.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\\mypic1.jpeg");
doc.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\\20140203_202325.jpg");            
doc.SaveAs2("C:\\MyDocument.doc");            
WordApp.Quit(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Can I get the pics one after the other or with somelines between them ?

Comment: Did you check the `AddPicture()` overloaded constructors? Maybe it says something about placing and image. It's just a guess cause i can't check it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using InlineShapes instead of Shapes on the document object like this:

```
var WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();         
WordApp.Documents.Add();
WordApp.Visible = true;         
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture("c:\\mypic1.jpeg");
doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture("c:\\20140203_202325.jpg");            
doc.SaveAs2("C:\\MyDocument.doc");            
WordApp.Quit(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

This will put the pictures one after the other (bear in mind if the first picture is so big that the second won't fit on the same page, it'll go onto a 2nd page).

Hope that helps,
Jon

Comment: Hi that did help, now if I want a line written between each pic like  
PIC1
Comment1
Pic2
Comment2

How would that be done ?

Comment: I don't have access to Visual Studio & Word at the moment to test, but if I remember right, you should be able to use the following code to insert text after the current position:
    `WordApp.Selection.InsertAfter("\r\nThis is some random text");`
(I've added the \r\n to add a line break before the text).

Answer (score 0):

Just found this: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191833(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191833%28v=office.15%29.aspx) it should help you.

You basically need to specify the position of each picture, something like:

```
 .AddPicture(FileName, LinkToFile, SaveWithDocument, Left, Top, Width, Height)
```